# How to run Phone Gap Application in multiple platform?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, cordova, sencha-touch

I have developed one simple application in phone-gap-android using eclipse and android SDK.
As phone-gap support multi mobile platform , I want to run this application in iPhone also.
How can i achieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each platform you want to get a port, you need to create a project in the dedicated environment and compile application as native one for each.

Your created source should be shared between project.

**Then for example :**

- to port your application to iPhone, you need a mac with installed Xcode, iPhone SDK downloaded and phonegap one installed.
  In xcode, create a phonegap project, import your sources, compile it, and it works !

Instructions on how to set up Phonegap for each OS can be found here: http://phonegap.com/start

If you are lucky, major modifications will not be needed between the devices.

An alternative would be to try PhoneGap Build: https://build.phonegap.com/